# Registration form shows too many fields after I make custom register form model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a custom registration form, but am running into trouble.

My `forms.py` has this:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    '''
    Form that makes user using just email as username
    '''
    error_messages= {
        "password_mismatch": _("Passwords do not match."),
        "duplicate_email": _("Email already exists."),
        "unique": _("Email already exists"),
    }
    register_username=  forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email"}))
    register_password1= forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Password"}))
    register_password2= forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Confirm password"}))

    def clean_username(self):
            username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
            try:
                User._default_manager.get(username=username)

                #if the user exists, then let's raise an error message
                raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_email'],  #user my customized error message
                                            code='duplicate_email',   #set the error message key
                )
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return username # great, this user does not exist so we can continue the registration process

    class Meta:
        model=  User
        fields= ("username",)
```

My `views.py` looks like this:

```
def login_register(request, template="pages/login_register.html"):
    registration_form= RegisterForm()
    return render(request, template, {"registration_form": registration_form})
```

Which leads to my registration form in `login_register.html` rendering like this:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="CSRF-TOKEN-HERE">
 <p><input autofocus="" id="id_username" maxlength="150" name="username" type="text" required=""></p>
 <p><input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" required=""></p>
 <p><input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" required=""></p>
 <p><input id="id_register_username" name="register_username" placeholder="Email" type="text" required=""></p>
 <p><input id="id_register_password1" name="register_password1" placeholder="Password" type="password" required=""></p>
 <p><input id="id_register_password2" name="register_password2" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" required=""></p> 
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

I only want the last three `input` tags to be used. My goal is for my registration form to have three fields: Email, password, and password confirmation. Why is Django loading the three extra top `input` fields and how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserCreationForm` already provide password and passwod confirmation. So you just need to override only username field, rename register_username:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm) :
    username = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email"}))

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)

            #if the user exists, then let's raise an error message
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_email'],  #user my customized error message
                                        code='duplicate_email',   #set the error message key
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username # great, this user does not exist so we can continue the registration process

    class Meta:
        model=  User
        fields = ("username",)
```